# "Module Not found" React loading class from index.js

Tags: reactjs, class

I keep getting the error "Module not found: Can't resolve './components/dndEditor' in '/Users/bob/Documents/GitHub/Active/DevComponents/DragDropComponents/src'"

I have scaled the code right back to the basics and it still is not working I must be doing something fundamentally wrong (I am more used to working with functional components than classes). The urls are pointing the files as visual studio is autocompleting the URL.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DndEditor from './components/dndEditor';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DndEditor />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and the class is

```
import React from 'react';


export default class DndEditor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>gfd </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine there might be something wrong with the file name .
Check the below link of codesandbox . It is working there
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-shaw-v210y

**index.js file**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import DndEditor from "./DndEditor";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <DndEditor />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**DndEditor.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default class DndEditor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is DndEditor </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```